# Custom front-end validation for dynamically added field using Symfony 3 forms

Tags: html, symfony, validation, symfony-forms

I'm running into an issue where the default HTML front end form validation is not applying to a particular field in a Symfony 3 form I've created.

The field itself is an instance of a custom field type that is a child of the EntityType class. Choices can be dynamically added to this field via jQuery and these changes are reflected in the form object by adding the new choices to it in the PreSumbmitEvent callback. All of this works.

The issue that I am having is caused by a jQuery plugin I have to use that hides Symfony Forms' generated select field and appends to it a multiselect widget that consists of a dropdown of checkboxes. These checkboxes dynamically select options from the hidden select element as the boxes are checked.

The fact that the select element is hidden also hides the tool tip provided by HTML5 front-end validation so the form fails silently when a user hasn't filled out this field.

Apparently, HTML front-end validation can't validate a group of check boxes which means I can't delegate validation to the widget using HTML's built in form validation. Using Symfony's 'error_mapping' functionality won't work either because the widget isn't defined in the form class. I would like to implement some sort of custom front-end validation for this field, but I'm not sure how to halt the form from submitting using JavaScript in the case that the field is empty.

How do I halt a Symfony form from submitting on the front end?  What is HTML5 front-end validation doing to stop Symfony Form submission and is there a way for me to do this using JavaScript?